# Kinect V2 javascript joints object is empty

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-2013, kinect

While developing win 8.1 store app using kinect v2 , i had some issue , and this is a part of my code :

```
mysensor = WindowsPreview.Kinect.KinectSensor.getDefault();                
                mysensor.open();
                console.log(mysensor);
                var isopen_timer = setInterval(function () {
                    if (mysensor.isOpen) {
                        console.log("sensor is opened");
                        myreader = mysensor.bodyFrameSource.openReader();
                        myreader.addEventListener('framearrived', handleFrame);
                        clearInterval(isopen_timer);
                    }

                }, 10);


                //open reader and listen for update


                //called on each frame updated
                function handleFrame(e)
                {

                    var frame = e.frameReference.acquireFrame();            


                    if (frame) {
                        frame.getAndRefreshBodyData(bodies);

                        for (var i=0;i<6;i++) {
                            if (bodies[i].isTracked) {
                                var joints = bodies[i].joints
                                console.log(Object.keys(joints));
                            }
                            else {

                            }
                        }
                        frame.close();
                    }
                }
```

my sensor opens , and everything works well , and i get a tracked body , but when i try to access `body.joints` object , and try to list keys , i get an empty array.

anyone has an idea of what may be wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be weird , but i thought to answer my own question just in case anyone was looking for issue.

the `lookup` method is the key:

as for now refrence and support for kinect v2 javascript API is very weak , but after some digging with MS samples here is the answer , use lookup method on body.joints to retrieve joint data.

the `lookup` method works as following `body.joints.lookup(joint_index)`, where joints count cannot exceed 25 ( max joint_index is 24 starting from 0 ), this method will return an object with detailed joint data like (x,y,z).

you can ignore the untrackd joints as every joint has the following properties:

`type` , and `trackingstate`

**Tracking State:**

**Inferred**    Joint data is inferred by calculating it from other tracked joints. Since the data is calculated, confidence in the data is very low.
(Property value : 0)

**NotTracked**  Joint data is not tracked; there is no joint data available.
(Property value : 1)

**Tracked** Joint data is tracked and available. Since the data is tracked, confidence in the data is very high. (Property value : 2)

**Joint Type**

please refer to table found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.jointtype.aspx)